# Why do I need to wrap array variable with curly brackets in PHP sometimes

Tags: php

I am trying to create two related drop down menus, where decision on one affects the options on the other. I ran into this interesting thing where in my second foreach loop, where I pass $subcategory['id'], it shows me an error. If wrap {$subcategory['id']} in curly braces it works fine. I want to understand why this is happening.

```
<?php
$categories = [
  [
    'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Furniture', 'subcategories' => [
      ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Beds'],
      ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Benches'],
      ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Cabinets'],
      ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Chairs & Stools'],
      ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Consoles & Desks'],
      ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Sofas'],
      ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Tables']
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Lighting', 'subcategories' => [
      ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Ceiling'],
      ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Floor'],
      ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Table'],
      ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Wall']
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Accessories', 'subcategories' => [
      ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Mirrors'],
      ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Outdoor & Patio'],
      ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Pillows'],
      ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Rugs'],
      ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Wall Decor & Art'],
    ]
  ]
];

  $category_id = isset($_GET['category_id']) ? (int) $_GET['category_id'] : 0;

  foreach($categories as $category) {
    if($category['id'] == $category_id) {

      $subcategories =   $category['subcategories'];
foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
  echo "<option value=\" {$subcategory['id']} \">";
  echo $subcategory['name'];
  echo "</option>";
}


    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: String interpolation with complex expressions requires curly braces. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: instead of 3 echos break out of PHP, or use `printf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $subcategory['id'], $subcategory['name'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are echoing an array entry inside a double quoted string.

```php
echo "hello $another_variable"; //works if $another_variable can be converted to string
echo "hello $arr['something']"; //error anyway
echo "hello {$arr['something']}"; //works
```

Basically, if you need to do something more complex than just using a simple `$variable`, you have to either use:

- The curly brackets syntax: `echo "my {$variable['foobar']}";`
- Concatenation: `echo "my ".$variable['foobar'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can interpolate values from arrays using simple syntax (no curly braces) if you don't quote the array key. You can see [an example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-38) of this in the simple syntax section of the PHP string documentation.

```
echo "<option value=\"$subcategory[id]\">";
```

If you want to do anything more complicated than that, then you'll need to use complex syntax (curly braces).